# Confirmar el cierre

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy intentando hacer un programilla y quiero añadir una ventana al pulsar la X para asegurarse de cerrar el programa por si acaso se le da sin querer, he conseguido hacer la ventana pero en los botones pone Yes y No, me gustaría cambiar el botón de Yes por Sí. Y me preguntaba si hay alguna manera de hacerlo.

Aqui dejo el código con simplemente la ventana principal y la ventana para confirmar el cierre:

```
import sys
import csv
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QDialog, QLabel, QComboBox, QAction, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QMessageBox, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Establecer el título de la ventana
        self.setWindowTitle("Comprobación cableado")
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        confirm_close = QMessageBox.question(
            self, "Confirmar cierre", "¿Está seguro de que desea cerrar la ventana?",
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        
        if confirm_close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes usar el método `Question` directamente, debes armar el message box *a mano* para tener chance de personalizar el texto de los botones. Por ejemplo:

```
box = QMessageBox()
box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
box.setWindowTitle('Confirmar cierre')
box.setText('¿Está seguro de que desea cerrar la ventana?')
box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No)
buttonY = box.button(QMessageBox.Yes)
buttonY.setText('Si')
buttonN = box.button(QMessageBox.No)
buttonN.setText('No cerrar')
box.exec_()

if box.clickedButton() == buttonY:
    event.accept()
elif box.clickedButton() == buttonN:
    event.ignore()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el texto del botón "Yes" a "Sí" en el cuadro de diálogo de confirmación de cierre, puedes utilizar la función setButtonText() del cuadro de mensaje QMessageBox. Aquí tienes el código actualizado:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMessageBox


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Establecer el título de la ventana
        self.setWindowTitle("Comprobación cableado")
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        confirm_close = QMessageBox.question(
            self, "Confirmar cierre", "¿Está seguro de que desea cerrar la ventana?",
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        
        # Cambiar el texto del botón "Yes" a "Sí"
        confirm_close.button(QMessageBox.Yes).setText("Sí")
        
        if confirm_close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ya había probado eso anteriormente y no me funcionaba, con tu código lo copio y pego tal cual y aparentemente tampoco funciona.

Comment: Intentaste chechar que todas las librerias que ocupas ya las tengas descargadas

Comment: Yo diría que si que tengo odas las librerias correspondientes que necesito todo se abre correctamente y de todo solo que a la hora de darle a la X con tu código el botón no cambia y aun encima no funciona como antes ahora si lo doy a No o a Yes el programa deja de funcionar.